# Test if an integer is prime

Tags: algorithm, haskell

```
isPrime::Integer->Bool
isPrime n=not (hasfactor n 2(div n 2))

hasfactor::Integer->Integer->Integer->Bool
hasfactor n low high
    |low>high=False
    |mod n low==0=True
    |otherwise = hasfactor n (low+1) high
```

I understand most of the code, except for the second line, `not (hasfactor n 2(div n 2))`. Why is the higher bound `(div n 2)`?
Say if we `test 8`, then `(hasfactor n 2(div n 2))` is `hasfactor 8 2 4`, I don't see the point of dividing `8` here.

Answer (score 3):

here it's using the fact that the smallest prime factor of an integer is 2, so the largest can be at most n/2.

A better algorithm will check numbers up to sqrt(n) to find whether there is a factor or not.

something like this

```
prime n = null [ k | k <- [2..n], k*k <= n, mod n k == 0 ]
```

though you need to handle `1` as a special case as non prime

**UPDATE**

to short circuit the check between sqrt(n) to n for prime numbers, this might be a better approach

```
prime n = null [ k | k <- takeWhile (\x -> x*x<=n) [2..], mod n k == 0 ]
```

Comment: That's not the best way to check only up to the square root, since it has to loop through `2..n` and repeatedly immediately discard every number from `sqrt n..n`. Discarding all those numbers takes a lot of time. The code in the question deals with only half the numbers this does.